# Keras multi input CNN only predicts one class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-science

---Update: problem is solveed(partly)----------

Can someone explain why this made such a huge difference:

I changed the following:

```
 output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(batchnorm)

    model = Model(
    inputs=[model_one_input, model_two_input],
    outputs=output
    )
```

to

```
    output = Dense(3)(batchnorm)
    softmax = Activation("softmax")(output)

    model = Model(
    inputs=[model_one_input, model_two_input],
    outputs=softmax
    )
```

Now i get still weird results but better when testing:

```
# Epoch 2:
 loss: 0.0069 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0632 - val_accuracy: 0.6667
# Epoch 10:
loss: 0.0069 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0570 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

I have a shallow convolutional model which is used to predict 3 different images.

I have two datasets and i have balanced the data so that all three class are distributed the same.

My problem is that the model training acc and validation acc cannot get above 80%.
When i run the model predict it only predicts one of the three classes which i find weird.

I have tried many different setup and checked the labels of the images and so on. It all looks fine. So i am starting to think it is a problem with my architecture maybe?

```
def get_covn_base(input_layer, img_shape):
    input = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=img_shape)(input_layer)
    acti01 = Activation("relu")(input)
    pool01 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(acti01)
    covn02 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3))(pool01)
    acti02 = Activation("relu")(covn02)
    pool02 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(acti02)
    covn03 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3))(pool02)
    acti03 = Activation("relu")(covn03)
    pool03 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(acti03)
    covn04 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(pool03)
    acti04 = Activation("relu")(covn04)
    pool04 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(acti04)
    flatten = Flatten()(pool04)
    return flatten

def get_shallow_cnn(img_shape):

    model_one_input = Input(shape=img_shape)
    model_one = get_covn_base(model_one_input, img_shape)

    model_two_input = Input(shape=img_shape)
    model_two = get_covn_base(model_two_input, img_shape)

    concat_feature_layer = concatenate([model_one, model_two])
    fully_connected_dense_big = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(concat_feature_layer)
    batchnorm = BatchNormalization()(fully_connected_dense_big)
    #acti = Activation('relu')(fully_connected_dense_big)
    fully_connected_dense_medium = Dense(512, activation="relu")(batchnorm)
    batchnorm = BatchNormalization()(fully_connected_dense_medium)
    fully_connected_dense_small = Dense(256, activation="relu")(batchnorm)
    batchnorm = BatchNormalization()(fully_connected_dense_small)
    output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(batchnorm)

    model = Model(
    inputs=[model_one_input, model_two_input],
    outputs=output
    )

    
    return model


 model = get_shallow_cnn(get_img_input_shape(True))


    opt = Adam(learning_rate=start_lr)

    model.compile(
        loss=loss_function,
        optimizer=opt,
        metrics=[tensorflow.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]
    )
```

Here's the test and training of the above:

[training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDZ8G.png)

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzr9p.png)

The labels of the prediction and true looks fine to me so if someone has experienced this problem or has some advice on this?

[Arhcitecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TTfy.png)

-----------UPDATE------------

I have just run a few test with only 3 images one image pr. class. I used the same images for training and validation with no shuffle. The metrics acc gave me the below

The label:

```
#labels
i = [1. 0. 0.]
i = [0. 0. 1.]
i = [0. 1. 0.]

# Model result 10 epochs:
epoch 2:
 loss: 0.0110 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0467 - val_accuracy: 0.3333
epoch 10:
loss: 0.0021 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.0331 - val_accuracy: 0.6667
```

so something is clearly off... How can it only predict 33% when its the same exact images?

Comment: Ok lots of questions, what is your loss function? (you haven't shown that), what is the target class distribution? (how many samples for each class in test and train data). If your model is prediction only 1 class majority of the time, it's possible that you dont have balanced the data, else your accuracy would have been around 33%, can you double check this?

Comment: My loss is categorical crossentropy and i am using ADAM optimizer. I Have a custom datagenerator which feeds the network with 1000 images of each class. For test i have only 70 images of each class and validation has around 200 images of each class. Each class has a catgegorical label = [0, 1, 0] (example)

Comment: The test data of 70 images as well as validation data of 200, what is the class distribution for these? Are these balanced?

Comment: Yes i meant that for test i have 3 class x70 images same for validation. Look at my update i have found something rather odd.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might come accross a multiclassification problem (3 classes) where the model only predict 33-66% of the class and leaves one out of the equation then add all activation functions as layers instead of strings. The activation function is not added in tensorflow 2.7 in my case with the keras functional api.